# php xml parsing

Tags: php, xml

```
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
```

i hava an xml object like this  which is retruned from a webservice. how can i parse this in PHP?????

Answer (score 2):

Use any of php's XML modules, [for example SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).